# android radiobutton array

Tags: java, android, arrays, radio-button

I'm trying to make a binary clock-style application with RadioButtons.
The layout is something like this:

o o o

o * o

Which would represent 2.

I've figured out how to print it out with ones and zeroes on screen and now I'd like to use the radiobuttons instead.
The method I'm using is this:

```
public void displayButtons()
{
    int[] binArray = new int[6];

    binArray = exec.toBinary(gregCal.get(GregorianCalendar.SECOND));

    for(int i = 0 ; i < binArray.length; i++ )
    {

        if(binArray[i] == 0)
            rButtons[i].setChecked(false);
        else 
            rButtons[i].setChecked(true);

    }
}
```

the toBinary method performs a binary conversion, in this case seconds, and returns an array of ones and zeroes.
I've made an array of radiobuttons as follows:

```
    private RadioButton rB0, rB1,rB2,rB3, rB4, rB5;
private RadioButton[] rButtons = new RadioButton[6];

    rButtons[0] = rB0;
    rButtons[1] = rB1;
    rButtons[2] = rB2;  
    rButtons[3] = rB3;
    rButtons[4] = rB4;  
    rButtons[5] = rB5;
```

I tried initiating the radiobutton array like this:

```
private RadioButton[] rButtons = {rB0, rB1,rB2,rB3, rB4, rB5};
```

but that gave me a runtime error..

The buttons don't update even though I've placed the displayButtons() method next to the method that prints out the ones and zeroes correctly.

I hope I haven't forgotten to include something important to solve this problem.
Please advice.

edit:
My log as follows

08-16 12:42:33.453: D/AndroidRuntime(1041): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
08-16 12:42:33.453: D/AndroidRuntime(1041): CheckJNI is ON
08-16 12:42:34.323: D/AndroidRuntime(1041): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
08-16 12:42:34.362: D/AndroidRuntime(1041): Shutting down VM
08-16 12:42:34.383: D/dalvikvm(1041): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 71% free 297K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 1ms+2ms
08-16 12:42:34.393: D/dalvikvm(1041): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-16 12:42:34.413: I/AndroidRuntime(1041): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
08-16 12:42:34.882: D/AndroidRuntime(1051): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
08-16 12:42:34.882: D/AndroidRuntime(1051): CheckJNI is ON
08-16 12:42:35.592: D/AndroidRuntime(1051): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
08-16 12:42:35.653: I/ActivityManager(60): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=se.macke.binarycounter/.MainActivity } from pid 1051
08-16 12:42:35.732: D/AndroidRuntime(1051): Shutting down VM
08-16 12:42:35.752: D/dalvikvm(1051): GC_CONCURRENT freed 102K, 69% free 320K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 2ms+5ms
08-16 12:42:35.802: I/AndroidRuntime(1051): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
08-16 12:42:35.802: D/dalvikvm(1051): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-16 12:42:35.922: I/ActivityManager(60): Start proc se.macke.binarycounter for activity se.macke.binarycounter/.MainActivity: pid=1060 uid=10035 gids={}
08-16 12:42:37.812: I/ActivityManager(60): Displayed se.macke.binarycounter/.MainActivity: +2s103ms
08-16 12:42:42.933: D/dalvikvm(132): GC_EXPLICIT freed 50K, 51% free 2842K/5767K, external 2295K/2866K, paused 82ms

Comment: Use radioGroup class.And show your log

Answer (score 0):

rB0, rB1... rb5 haven't been initialized. You could define them in yout xml file and then use

```
rB0 = (RadioButton) findViweById( R.yourxml.rB0id )
```